# Reading data out of an ADC (MCP3001) with python (SPI)

Tags: python

I try to read some data from an ADC with python, but unfortunatly it doesn't work. I hope someone has a hint for me, because my script creates only chaos-data. But I don't see the mistake with the bits...

I've updated the script below as I'm reading 16 bits and cut of the first and the last 3 bits. I need the 10 middle bits for the data - if I understand the datasheet correctly...

**Datasheet MCP3001:** (Page 15) http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21293C.pdf

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

HIGH = True
LOW  = False

def readAnalogData(SCLKPin, MOSIPin, MISOPin, CSPin):
    GPIO.output(CSPin,   HIGH)    
    GPIO.output(CSPin,   LOW)
    GPIO.output(SCLKPin, LOW)

    adcvalue = 0
    for i in range(16):
        GPIO.output(SCLKPin, HIGH)
        GPIO.output(SCLKPin, LOW)
        adcvalue <<= 1
        if(GPIO.input(MISOPin)):
            adcvalue |= 0x01
    adcvalue >>= 3
    adcvalue &= 0x3ff
    time.sleep(0.5)

    return adcvalue

SCLK        = 11 # Serial-Clock
MOSI        = 10 # Master-Out-Slave-In
MISO        = 9 # Master-In-Slave-Out
CS          = 17 # Chip-Select

GPIO.setup(SCLK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOSI, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MISO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(CS,   GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    print readAnalogData(SCLK, MOSI, MISO, CS)
```

Comment: What clock rate does successive `GPIO.output(SCLKPin, ...)` statements produce? Have you tried slowing down the communications with a `time.sleep(...)` after every `GPIO.output` statement?

Comment: How can I find out which clockrate?

Comment: Measure it with an oscilloscope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory read of the data sheet and your code, it looks like you're trying to discard the data from the initial 3 clock cycles by converting to a `str` and using `str` slicing

```
adcvalue = str(adcvalue)
adcvalue = adcvalue[3:12]
adcvalue = int(adcvalue)
```

If so, this will not work. `adcvalue` is an `int` and converting it to a `str` will produce a decimal (base 10) string. Instead, either don't sample data during the first three cycles, or use a bit mask to strip it from the integer (ie `adcvalue &= 0x1ff`)

In addition, you seem to be sampling data on the negative clock edge, however this is when the data is in a transient state. I suspect you either need to put in a delay here, or sample on the +ve clock edge when the data has stabilized.

**EDIT**

As stated above, try sampling on the +ve clock edge. Figure 6-1 on pg.16 of the datasheet shows this. Also it looks like it pumps out 9 bits in MSB format, then repeats the data in LSB format (see Fig 6-2), so I don't think you want to keep 10 bits. You probably only need to clock out a total of 12bits, then discard the first 3.

Something like (untested):

```
def readAnalogData(SCLKPin, MOSIPin, MISOPin, CSPin):
    GPIO.output(CSPin,   HIGH)    
    GPIO.output(CSPin,   LOW)

    adcvalue = 0
    for i in range(12):
        GPIO.output(SCLKPin, LOW) # reverse order of hi/lo here
        GPIO.output(SCLKPin, HIGH)
        adcvalue <<= 1
        if(GPIO.input(MISOPin)):
            adcvalue |= 0x01
    adcvalue >>= 3
    # adcvalue &= 0x3ff <- commented out this line as should be no longer necessary

    return adcvalue
```

Comment: So I need the bitmask "0x1ff8"? And on which place do I have to add a delay?

Comment: Unfortunatly "adcvalue &= 0x1ff8" doesn't work... I added also "adcvalue = adcvalue * 3.3/1024" and I'm getting values betwwen 8.0 and 10.5. But the real input is 1.2V

Comment: In your code you read 15 bits and mask the first and last 3, leaving 9 bits in the middle. So you should right shift by 3 `adcvalue >>= 3` and then use the bitmask 0x1ff.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I guess I have some more mistakes. I need 16 bits, instead of 15 bits and leave 10 bits in the middle. So my code should be: 

   for i in range(16):

and  

    adcvalue >>= 3 
    adcvalue &= 0x3ff

But still it doesn't work correctly as I get values like "662, 653, 673, 745, 769".

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Basically the previous answer but tweaked and tested.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

def ReadMCP3001():
    GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(11, False)  # CLK low
    GPIO.output(7, False)   # /CS low
    adcvalue = 0
    for i in range(13):
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        adcvalue <<= 1
        if(GPIO.input(9)):
            adcvalue |= 0x001
    GPIO.output(7, True)    # /CS high
    adcvalue &= 0x3ff
    return adcvalue
```